# Why is a dictionary of Encodable key and values not encodable itself?

Tags: swift

Why doesn't a Dictionary of type `[String: Encodable]()` able to cast to Encodable?

```
let dictionary = [String: Encodable]()
let test = dictionary is Encodable //Returns false
```

But a dictionary of `[String: String]()` does work

```
let dictionaryTwo = [String: String]()
let test = dictionaryTwo is Encodable //Returns true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [conditional conformance of `Dictionary` to `Encodable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/62fce8a2691b7722b619d1f3a9489956da9d226a/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5603) looks as follows:

```swift
extension Dictionary: Encodable where Key: Encodable, Value: Encodable {
   // ...
}
```

In English, this means that a `Dictionary` is `Encodable` when its `Key` and `Value` types are each types which themselves conform to `Encodable`.

However, `[String: Encodable]` (also spelled `[String: any Encodable]`) is not such a type, because `any Encodable` is not itself a type which can conform to `Encodable` — it's a way to spell a *constraint* on a type, rather than a type itself.

For more information, see other questions like [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

Answer (score -1):

`Encodable` is a protocol, and protocols do not conform to themselves. That is the first issue. To look at it at a more tangible level, the issue is that just because a group of objects are `Encodable` doesn't mean they can be encoded in the same way.

`[String:String]` gives enough information so that, because the key and the value are `Encodable`, the the dictionary is. Here is an example that shows why `[String:Encodable]()` can't conform.

Suppose I have `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
    let myString: String
    let myInt: Int
}

struct Bar: Encodable {
    let yourString: String
    let yourInt: Int
}
```

Now I have my dictionary:

```
var dictionary: [String: Encodable] = [:]
dictionary["fooExample"] = Foo(myString: "whatever", myInt: 100)
dictionary["barExample"] = Bar(yourString: "something", yourInt: 20)
```

We have a dictionary with keys and values that are all `Encodable`. If you take a look, though, `dictionary["fooExample"]` and `dictionary["barExample"]` encode completely differently. So even though values can *individually* encode, it doesn't mean that the dictionary with those values can encode.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but did want to say: while you're right to point out that several different values in a collection of `any Encodable` could encode differently, this isn't much of an issue. For example, it's perfectly valid to have an array of the _same_ type where several values encode very differently from one another. _However_, this is more of a problem when you go to _decode_, because you cannot attempt to decode a collection of `any Decodable`, because the _static_ type information is necessary in order to know which `init(from:)` needs to be called

Comment: That's a fair point to make.